# Caching DOM elements and jQuery performance

Tags: jquery, performance, dom

I would like to know which approach could have a better performance using jQuery on a complex DOM structure. If you have any experience or other approach, I would love have your opinion.

A)

```
$("#item2").parents(".item-row").next().children().eq(2).addClass("focus");
```

B)

```
var item2 = $("#item2");
item2.parents(".item-row").next().children().eq(2).addClass("focus");
```

C)

```
var item2 = $(document.getElementById(item2));
item2.parents(".item-row").next().children().eq(2).addClass("focus");
```

Comment: They are all the same, since jQuery will anyway use getElementById for 1st and 2nd.

Comment: In case you are not selecting an element more than once you should not cache your selection by assigning it to some variable.

Comment: Could I have any performance improvement if when reference the same DOM element I use the cached version var item2 = $("#item2"); item2.dosmt(); item2.dosmt(); ???

Comment: @GibboK: This [**link**](http://jquery-howto.blogspot.in/2008/12/caching-in-jquery.html) might help you...

Comment: if you like add it as an answer I will accept it, many thanks

Comment: The speed increase depends on how many times you access the element, and what the selector is. Some selectors are *much* slower than others. E.g. http://jsperf.com/pg-jquery-selector-tests/2

Comment: caching will only give significant improvement if doing repeated searches for same element which code shown doesn't do